# OpenCV get thumbnail from buffer

Tags: python, django, opencv

I am trying to write a script that allows users to upload videos and grabs a thumbnail image made from the first frame of the video. The script I have now doesn't throw any errors, but when the thumbnail gets created it is a broken image and is only 13b, where I would expect it to be at least a couple kb.

```
f = request.FILES['media-video']
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(f.read())
img = cap.read()
thumb_buf = StringIO.StringIO()
thumb_buf.write(img)
content = thumb_buf.getvalue()
blob_service.put_blob('vid-thumbnail', thumbnail_name, content, x_ms_blob_type='BlockBlob')
thumb_buf.close()
cap.release()
```

If I do `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(f)` instead of `f.read()` I get an error saying `an integer is required`.

If I use `cv2.imencode('.png', img[1])` to write the image to buffer instead of using `StringIO`, I get an error `opencv/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:429: error: (-215) code in function imencode`

Any ideas as to why the script is creating a broken thumbnail image?

**EDIT**: Looks like the issue is with `VideoCapture(f.read())`. img returns `None` before it is even written to StringIO.

Comment: get rid of that StringIO, it's great for strings , but bad for binary information. i think, you wanted [imencode](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imencode) in the 1st place there

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a bug.

`read()` returns a tuple (retval, image), so change line 3 to:

```
hello, img = cap.read()
```

Comment: No errors were thrown, but doing that creates an image 0b instead of 13b

Comment: I noticed your posted code still contains the bug. Try fixing as per my answer...